# Load php results with .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to load the result of a php page with .load() inside a html page. I want to load the results inside a div element with id `id="div3_example_result"` that i have included in the html page... I want the result to appear when I press one of the calendar date, because I am building a calendar..

I have build this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){         
        g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
            useMode:1,
            isStripped:true,
            target:"div3_example"                       

        g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
            var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();
            alert("a date was just selected and the date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);
            $('#div3_example_result').load('insert.php');               
        });         
    };          
</script>
```

and this is the html part

```
<body>      
    <br />        
    <div id="div3_example" style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 100px; border:dashed 1px red; width:205px; height:230px;">            
    </div>            
    <div id="div3_example_result" style="height:20px; line-height:20px; margin:10px 0 0 0; border:dashed 1px #666;">
    </div>            
</body>
```

But it does not function. Only the alert message appears when I click in one date, but the div is still empty..No result is uploaded...Can you help me please? Thanks in advance...

The php file:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Lidhja me databazen nuk mund te kryhet' .mysql_error(). ' </body></html>');
  }
if(!mysql_select_db("Axhenda",$con))
die('Nuk mund te hapet databaza Axhenda'.mysql_error(). '</body></html>');




$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Perdoruesi");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you mean jQuery `.load()` https://api.jquery.com/load/? `window.onload =` only triggers a function, when all elements in the "DOM" have loaded. ;)

Comment: Sorry the link was invisible

Comment: Changed the comment, the link was "invisible". Check this page out, should work. (y)

Comment: I have seen that link..Thats where i start to buil my function...but it does not function now...i doont know if I have put the $('#div3_example_result').load('insert.php'); in the right place. can you help me please...

Comment: Oh, sorry, am accustomed to `$.ajax({})` and overlooked your function, ehemm. So, do you have any output in the `console`? Do you `echo` anything in the `insert.php`? Can you put that up?

Comment: I put the php file above...thanks for trying to help me

Comment: I have also one question...If this that I ask above is not possibel is there any way that when I click in one date to go to a php or html page?

Comment: That should be possible. Do you have any output in the `console` do you know what that is? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers Sorry for asking! It's important. ;)

Comment: I cant open the link you gave to me..it said Object not found!   So I dont know how to find output in the console...

Comment: Eah, do a reload on that link. On what browser are you?

Comment: i found how to open it...it was one error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at these line: $('#div3_example_result').load('insert.php');

Comment: Ok, you need to install `jQuery` first, "best" would be to use this link `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and put it into your `HTML` before the other javascript functions.

Comment: i try it nothing happens

Comment: No output in the console? Do a right mouse click in the console and select `Log XMLHttpRequests`. What do you see?

Comment: Thanks a lot.....Oh my god it function know....You are my saver!!! Where can I make accept your answer?

Comment: No, that's on house, glad to help though!!